# Iterating tweets and saving them in a shapefile with tweepy and shapefile

Tags: if-statement, twitter, tweepy, shapefile, points

I am searching for tweets and want to save them in a shapefile. Iterating through tweets is going well and when I use print statements I can get exactly what I want. I am attempting to put these tweets in a point shapefile. For some reason it does not accept the iterating of the if statement. So how do I iterate through my tweets and save them one by one in my point shapefile with only the tweet.text and tweet.id attached?

I got inspired by looking at the following link: https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/

```
import tweepy
import shapefile

consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."
access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweetsaspoints = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)

page = 1
while True:
    statuses = api.search(q="*",count=1000, geocode="52.015106,5.394287,150km")
    if statuses:
        for status in statuses:
            print status.geo
            tweetsaspoints._shapes.extend([status.geo['coordinates']])
            tweetsaspoints.records.extend([("TEXT","Test")])
    else:
        # All done
        break
    page += 1  # next page

tweetsaspoints.save('shapefiles/test/point')
```

I do not understand the page part. I seem to iterate through the same tweets over and over again. Also, I am not succeeding in writing my coordinates and data to a point shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, try to use:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    # process status here
    process_status(status)
```

Alternative:

```
page = 1
while True:
    statuses = api.user_timeline(page=page)
    if statuses:
        for status in statuses:
            # process status here
            process_status(status)
    else:
        # All done
        break
    page += 1  # next page
```

reference: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html

Comment: Still can't figure out how to put the coordinates into a point dataset with two added fields.

Comment: There is a good example under this link: https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/ about how to use shapefiles, I am not sure about the "extend" you may try using similar standard.

Also if you working in a specific shell, make sure you run the script with the right permissions.